# Can't import Beautiful Soup in Python 3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I'am using Ubuntu and I just used `apt` to install Beautiful Soup by running the command `sudo apt-get install python3-bs4`. Runnig `apt list --installed | grep bs4`
 gives the following output:

```
python3-bs4/xenial,xenial,now 4.4.1-1 all [installed]
```

In spite of this I can't import bs4. Here's the code and the error associated with it:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to pip install Beautiful Soup 4 into your virtual environment.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Why can't I install it normally with `apt`? Also, isn't it bad for me to have the same package installed from both `apt` and `pip`?

Comment: I recomend using `pip`. Be sure to check out [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install). Also make sure you are installing ` beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: @plx, py3.6 is certainly not the standard with 16.04 so apt installing is not going to add packages for it. Regardless, use a virtualenv and life will be a lot simpler.